# How to import data from a dump file to a specific schema in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Let us assume there's a database name `myDataBase`. There are four schema in this database named

1: `schema_1`

2: `schema_2`

3: `schema_3`

4: `schema_4`

I have created a dump of `schema_1` from this command `pg_dump  myDataBase --schema=schema_1 > schema_1_dump`

How to import `schema_1_dump` to only `schema_3` but not to any other schema

Answer (score 1):

probably the easiest is to first rename the existing schema_1

restore the dump

rename the new schema_1 to schema_3

restore the original schema_1 to its original name

eg psql:

```
 alter schema schema_1 rename to schema_1_backup;
 create schema schema_1;
 \i schema_1_dump
 drop schema_3 cascade;
 alter schema schema_1 rename to schema_3;
 alter schema schema_1_backup rename to schema_1;
```

This is going to annoy other users.

The other way is to change all the SQL commands to say  'schema3' instead of 'schema1'